# Replacing a managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean

Couple of questions on setting managed bean using CDI.
1. If a session bean is Injected into another using @Inject annotation, how to replace the entire session Bean? 
2. In CDI, Is it possible to define Injection to only inject (not to outject).

Comment: In the future, please ask separate questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

> *If a session bean is Injected into another using `@Inject` annotation, how to replace the entire session Bean?*

You don't. This requirement can mean only 1 thing: the session scope is the wrong scope for the bean in question. Perhaps you're looking for the [conversation scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html) instead.

If you really need to, you can always add some `clear()` method which clears the state (thus, all of its properties) of the session scoped bean, but this is still fishy. Just choose the right scope from the beginning on.